# Proof that if there exists some real $a, b$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{ax + b}=1$, then $f$ has an oblique asymptote.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

**Prove that:**

If there exists some real $a, b$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{ax + b} = 1$, then $f$ has an oblique asymptote.

**Ideas**:

- We can convert "$f$ has an oblique asymptote" to: $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x) - (ax+b)] = 0$.
- I think it's true, but I'm not sure how to prove it *carefully* while stating assumptions properly and using limit laws correctly.

Comment: You could take $f(x)=x+\sqrt x$, with $a=1, b=0$. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, since it is not true. If, for instance, $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ (the floor funtion), then$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1,$$but $f$ has no oblique asymptote.

Comment: What about proving the converse? If $f$ has an oblique asymptote, then...

Comment: Sure: if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)-(ax+b)=0$, then$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-(ax+b)}{ax+b}=0.$$But this is equivalent to the assertion that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{ax+b}=1.$$

Comment: What limit law or assumption are you making when you go from $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) - (ax+b) = 0$ to dividing by $ax + b$?

Comment: I am just using the fact that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and if $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks!