# Prove that if $f$ has an oblique asymptote, then there exists some reals $a, b$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{ax+b}=1$..

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

**Prove that:**

If $f$ has an oblique asymptote, then there exists some reals $a, b$ so that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{ax + b} = 1$

**Ideas**:

- We can convert "$f$ has an oblique asymptote" to: $\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x) - (ax+b)] = 0$.
- I think it's true, but I'm not sure how to prove it *carefully* while stating assumptions properly and using limit laws correctly.

**Note:** 
I have submitted a similar question before on another account ([Not sure how to approach this limit proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488462/not-sure-how-to-approach-this-limit-proof?noredirect=1#comment7172980_3488462)), except it is the converse of this implication and it does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{f(x)-(ax+b)}{ax+b} \right]=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\frac{f(x)}{ax+b} -1\right]
$$

Comment: Why are you allowed to divide by $ax+b$? What assumptions or laws are you following?

Comment: For $x \to \infty$  we have $ax+b \ne 0$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Note that your form is weaker because
$\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+c}
-\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+b}
=\dfrac{(b-c)f(x)}{(ax+c)(ax+b)}
$
so that,
if
$\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+c}
\to 1$
for any $c$ then
$\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+c}
\to 1$
for all $c$.

Even more,
if
$f(x) -(ax+b)
\to 0$
then
$\dfrac{f(x)}{ax+g(x)}
\to 1
$
where $g(x)$
is any function such that
$\dfrac{g(x)}{x}
\to 0
$.